# Android : game loop pause/resume issue

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview, game-engine, android-lifecycle

I am able to pause/resume my game by making my game thread(which holds/synchronized with surfaceview)  wait/notifyAll. This all runs well using the in game pause button.

However, when I click home/back button I am able to pause my game, but when I resumes my game by clicking on its icon, I receive non responsive game screen back to me.

I have put logs on OnResume() method but nothing gets printed in LogCat!
If I click on my game screen I get error dialog to "Force Close" or "Wait" on my game activity.

Why I am getting this non responsive screen as if my application Hangged after pause ?
How can I handle physical buttons in same way as inGame pause/resume button ?

here is my logcat view of the operation. you can see onResume sop not getting printed similar to onPause.

[image: LogCat View]

EDIT : Code called by my pause/resume button and by onPause/onResume functions
where "this" is thread class itself

```
protected void setPause(){
        synchronized (this) {
            isPaused = true;
                }
    }

    protected void setResume(){
        synchronized (this) {
            isPaused = false;
            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }
```

Game Loop Code :

```
synchronized (this) {
            while (running) {
                if (isPaused) {
                    try {
                        this.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Canvas c = null;

                    try {
                        c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                        synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                            view.onDraw(c);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (c != null) {
                            view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                        }
                    }
                    sleepTime = ticksPS
                            - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                    try {
                        if (sleepTime > 0)
                            sleep(sleepTime);
                        else
                            sleep(10);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This how I am calling it from surface view :

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                // start the game loop
                System.out.println("Starting Game Loop @@@@@@@@@");
                if(isPaused){
                    System.out.println("GamePaused");
                    gameLoopThread.setResume();
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Game Starting");
                    gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                }
                gameLoopThread.start();

            }
```

EDIT 2:
If I Pause my game using pause button and let my phone get locked automatically... after resuming I am able to play normally with out any issue.
As per logs I see surface destroyed is not getting called in this case.

Comment: What does your OnResume and OnPause code say?

Comment: check my update on the post under EDIT

Comment: I assume your method of pausing the game somehow "sleeps" on the UI thread.
This is not the way to do it. Show us the code that is executed if the game isPaused

Comment: I have added the code in the post, please help !

Answer (score 1):

After `onResume`, your `SurfaceView` is created again, but it lost all the data it had before (all info needed for `onDraw`). you have to save the data in `surfaceDestroyed` or before, and reload it in the `onCreate` of your surfaceview

Comment: how do I do that?
I have lots of random objects placed on the screen. How will I able to save my state for so many items? Should I simply Call Finish() and tell users to start all over ?

Comment: If I pause my game from pause button and let my phone get automatically locked, on resume all works well !!

Comment: use shared preferences to save. if you have an array of objects, i would turn it into a JSONObject and save it as string.

Comment: Can you show me in code how to reuse the objects when resuming the code?